# php - dynamically create div content from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

So, here is the page in discussion, [DONATION RESULTS](http://dutchgfx.com/DonationDemo/2/Results/)

What I did was I used the SQL DB to populate rows by totals, works great. Now, I want when the name is clicked, or the ammount is clicked, for a dialog to pop up with all the individual donations that person has recieved. To do this, I need to use

```
$eachone = mysql_query("SELECT donor_first,donor_last FROM dc_donations WHERE sponsoring='***'")
```

where *** needs to automatically fill with the data from the name/previous query. So for example, for the sponsor tk, when you click on the link tk, it should run

```
SELECT donor_first,donor_last FROM dc_donations WHERE sponsoring='tk'
```

It also needs to be nested inside another while loop. This works, outside of the while loop, just as a test. It retrieves all the names, however, not just the ones for that particular sponsor. But, when I put it inside the other while loop, to put the content inside the div, instead of in some random spot on the page, it doesn't work anymore.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($eachone))  {
        echo $row['donor_first'] . ' ' . $row['donor_last']. ' ';
            }
```

here is my entire code, sorry if its long, shouldnt be too bad.

[MY CODE (PASTEBIN)](http://pastebin.com/EFpey3vT)

Answer (score 0):

At Line 71, shouldn't you supposed to close `</a>` before `</td>`?
I recommend to check HTML generated to see what happened, if PHP isn't coming with error.
Give us more information to provide a better help.

Comment: Yeah it should be but for actual physical-code relation, meaning that it doesnt link anything extra by being back, but it actually doesn't affect code. How do I check HTML Generated?

Answer (score 0):

In line 63 you have opening  `<tr>` tag but it have no closing `</tr>`

Comment: Are you sure !, it corresponding to 'tr' in line 68.